# Hacer una función que descargue síncronamente una página y retorne su contenido

Tags: nodejs, descarga

Quisiera tener una función en *Node JS*, que retorne un archivo descargado de internet.

Encontré [esta respuesta en *StackOverflow*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944932/how-to-download-a-file-with-node-js-without-using-third-party-libraries/11944984#11944984), pero la diferencia es que guarda en un archivo lo descargado, y no retorna el resultado.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.jpg");
var request = http.get("http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/J---aiyznGQ/mqdefault.jpg", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer es, en vez de descargar un archivo, que retorne el contenido del archivo descargado, es decir, de forma síncrona.

Yo lo planteo de la siguiente manera.

```
function descargar(página) // página es "http://www..."
{
    var http = require('http');

    var descargado // Aquí se descarga y se almacena el contenido de lo descargado.

    // Una vez descargado, retornar el contenido. "<html><body>...."
    return descargado
}
```

¿Es posible hacer esto? ¿y de qué manera se podría hacer?

Comment: Hay un paquete en npm el cual no he usado, parece que no se mantine regularmente y el propio autor lo desaconseja para producción. https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request . Sin embargo, puedo escribir una respuesta utilizando Promises y async/await que cumple tus necesidades.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible realizar peticiones de forma síncrona, aunque no es lo recomendable. Véase, [`sync request`](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/sync-request).

Para completar la respuesta de Gerardo, te dejo un ejemplo funcional. Nota que en `Node.JS` no está disponible la API Fetch. Puedes utilizar cualquier paquete para realizar peticiones HTTP, que utilice Promises, como [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) o [`request-promise`](https://github.com/request/request-promise).

Utilizando Async/Await puedes escribir el código asíncrono de una manera secuencial y como en el ejemplo poder devolver el resultado procesado.

¡OJO!, una función asíncrona siempre devuelve una promesa que encapsula el valor `Promise<any>` y no el valor en sí. Por esa razón en el ejemplo encapsulamos la ejecución del proceso en otra función asíncrona.

**`EJEMPLOS EN NODE`** ([Ver ejemplo funcional online](https://runkit.com/joseahr/5a05827dff00cb00122cd765))

```
const axios = require('axios');
const requestPromise = require('request-promise-native');

const { promisify } = require('util');
const request = promisify(require('request'));

async function downloadAndProcess(url) {
  // Nota que en NodeJS no está disponible la API Fetch
  const response = await axios.get(url);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data.slice(0,10);
}

async function downloadAndProcessRP(url) {
  // Nota que en NodeJS no está disponible la API Fetch
  const response = await requestPromise.get(url, { json : true });
  console.log(response);
  return response.slice(0,10);
}

async function downloadAndProcessRequest(url) {
  // Nota que en NodeJS no está disponible la API Fetch
  const response = await request(url);
  //console.log(response.body);
  const data = JSON.parse(response.body);
  console.log(data);
  return data.slice(0,10);
}

async function main() {
  const dummyUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  let processed = await downloadAndProcess(dummyUrl);
  let processedRP = await downloadAndProcessRP(dummyUrl);
  let processedRequest = await downloadAndProcessRequest(dummyUrl);
  console.log(processed.length, processedRP.length, processedRequest.length);
}

main();
```

**`SNIPPET PARA NAVEGADOR`**

```js
async function downloadAndProcess(url) {
  // Nota que en NodeJS no está disponible la API Fetch
  const responseData = await fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
  
  return responseData.slice(0,10);
}

async function main() {
  const dummyUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

  let processed = await downloadAndProcess(dummyUrl);
  console.log(processed.length, processed);
}

main();
```

Comment: En un rato adapto la respuesta para NodeJS. Te en cuenta que la parte de `.then(res => res.json())` es específica de la API Fetch. En Node 8+ puedes utilizar la función promisify del paquete util en conjunción con el paquete request.

Comment: @ArtEze Te dejo varios ejemplos con las librerías axios, request-promise-native y (request + promisify). Saludos! =)

Comment: ¿Habrá alguna manera de hacer esto sin recurrir a paquetes no nativos?

Comment: Sí. Podrías "promisificando" el método request del paquete http. Aunque esa "promisificación" no sería tan directa.

Comment: Quise meter el `await` dentro de un `eval` y me tira error. [¿Por qué no puedo hacer esto?](https://runkit.com/arteze/sinc)... ¿Hay alguna alternativa?

Comment: `await` solo puede ser utilizado dentro de una función asíncrona (prefijada con `async`). Podrías usarlo así: `try { eval( (async function (){ await ... })() ) }...`

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo con una simple petición utilizando `async/await`. Esto solo funciona desde la versión de Node.js >= 7.6.0.

Para utilizar esta característica es necesario que la función donde estes utilizando `await` sea `async` en caso contrario no funcionará.

Ejemplo:

```
async function() { ... }
```

Una vez entendido esto pasamos a crear nuestra función `descargar`

```
async descargar(url) { ... }
```

En mi caso utilizaré [`axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) para evitar usar `http` y acortar código. Entonces el código que tienes como ejemplo quedaría ahora de la siguiente manera:

```
async descargar(url) {
    var axios = require('axios');
    var response = await axios.get(url);
    return response.data;
}
```

En lo anterior `await` lo que hace es 'esperar' a que se complete la `Promise` que retorna `axios.get` antes de continuar con la siguiente línea. Haciendo esto ya podemos utilizar `descargar` pero ten en cuenta que siempre que definas una función como `async` esta siempre va a retornar una `Promise`.

Ejemplo de uso con `Promise`:

```
var descarga = descargar('http://www.ejemplo.com/');
descarga.then(function(data) {
        // data contiene la información que necesitas
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error); // Manejar el error
    });
```

Suponiendo que quieres evitar una promesa, puedes volver a utilizar `async/await`.

Ejemplo de uso con `async/await`:

```
var descarga = await descargar('http://www.ejemplo.com/');
```

Ahora `descarga` contiene un string con la info que 'descarga' o mas bien obtiene de la petición. Pero recuerda que para hacerlo de la forma anterior necesita estar dentro de una función `async`, en caso de que tu llamada a `descargar` no este dentro de una función `async` podrías utilizar una [Immediately-invoked function expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression), quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
(async function() {
    try {
        var descarga = await descargar('http://www.ejemplo.com/');
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error); // Manejar el error
    }
})();
```

Creo que esto es todo lo que necesitas. Espero y te sirva.

Por último se me olvidaba, te dejo aquí la info sobre [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) y [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await) para que lo leas y aprendas como funcionan.

Comment: Me tira `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` en la palabra `descargar` (tengo Node v8.4.0).

Comment: Aah, faltaba `function`... `async function descargar(url) {`

Comment: @ArtEze no se que estes tratando de hacer pero recuerda que en node el objeto `window` no existe.

Comment: Puedes compartirme una imagen de tu código? Quiero reproducir el error. Debería funcionar y probablemente es problema de alguna librería. Te comparto una imagen funcionando: https://imgur.com/a/AQVqN

Comment: @ArtEze Solo quita el espacio que hay entre `descarga` y `.then`, quita ese salto de linea, que quede todo junto.

Comment: Me funciona perfectamente, el único error era de REPL con eso se corregía. Bueno, ya lo corriste al menos desde un archivo .js? El unhandled promise rejection se da cuando ocurre un error y no tienes un `catch`, https://imgur.com/vuK6ZKt intenta correrlo desde un archivo y si no te funciona me cambio a windows para comprobar.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68547/discussion-between-arteze-and-gerardo).